# Give an example of an injective continuous map...

Tags: general-topology

> Give an example of an injective continuous map of $(0,1)$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ which is not a homeomorphism onto the image of $(0,1)$.

Can anyone help me out here? This is part of a problem sheet on compactness oddly enough; yet, all I know from my notes is that a continuous, bijective map from a compact set is a homeomorphism onto the image of such a compact set.

Comment: Not sure why this has 5 upvotes, would you say it is "well researched"? It shows no effort. Giving hints is something I encourage but upvotes should be reserved for "this person has tried"

Answer (score 10):

HINT: $\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$

[image]

Comment: Out of curiosity, would a circle with one point removed also do the job?

Comment: @Clement: No, that actually *is* homeomorphic to $(0,1)$. You need to make one of the loose ends approach a point on the image.

Comment: Ha, I was wondering whether making the images of the two loose ends close to each other was enough (to contradict continuity of the inverse).

Comment: @Clement: No, as long as there’s an actual gap, even of one point, the inverse will be continuous.

Comment: I'll think about it to make sure I understand  -- thanks!

Comment: @Clement: My pleasure!

Answer (score 8):

**Hint** Find a suitable parameterization of the [figure eight curve](http://www-history.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/Curves/Eight.html):

[image]